# trying to run protoc on the cmd prompt

Tags: jupyter-notebook, protocol-buffers, tar, protoc

i am trying to run a code that recwires me to have protoc and when i run it i get C:\Users\Lenovo>protoc --version
'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
even though I downloaded it and put the protoc.exe file in my system variables
do you know why i might get this issue and for anyone that this command has worked with what tecnique did you use much appreciated

help from experts that know how it workssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: *put the protoc.exe file in my system variables* -- What, exactly, do you mean by that?  If you are talking about PATH, you don't put the executable in the PATH -- you put the directory that CONTAINS it.